# How to make questions using "who"?

Tags: grammar

I extracted this from L.R.H Chapman grammar two book.

An example was given like this :

> Question : Who did jack meet at the station?
>
> Answer : Jack met his uncle at the station

I am not sure whether is it correct to make every question like the example format given above.

Is this sentence correct?

Question : who did the rich woman pay yesterday?
Answer : The rich woman paid her servants yesterday.

I assume that the correct sentence would be "To whom did the rich woman pay yesterday?"

Here are the sentences for questions to be made :

> 1. The rich woman paid her servants yesterday.
> 2. I saw a lot of soldiers outside the palace.
> 3. The angry man hit the boy.
> 4. Mary wrote a letter to her aunt.
> 5. The teacher helped the weak pupil.
> 6. The old man knew everybody in the village.

Comment: One would hope that the book capitalizes "Jack".

Comment: All of these sentences are in the past tense. Therefore there is no auxiliary verb and non-subject _wh_-questions must use _do_-Support. So there are two types: _Who did the rich woman pay yesterday?_, with an object interrogative; and _Who paid the servants yesterday?_, with a subject interrogative -- therefore no Subject-Auxiliary Inversion or _do_-Support is necessary.

Comment: Why do you assume that “To whom did the rich woman pay?” would be the correct question? As your example sentences show, _pay_ does not take _to_ (except optionally if there is both a direct and an indirect object), and the statement is not “The rich woman paid *to her servants”. So why would there be a _to_ in the question form?

Answer (score 0):

> Question : Who did Jack meet at the station?
>
> Answer : Jack met his uncle at the station
>
> I am not sure whether is it correct to make every question like the
>   example format given above.

I am not sure either. The answer to a 'who' question should be a *person*, i.e.

> Question : Who did Jack meet at the station?
>
> Answer : His uncle.

Therefore it is difficult to answer the rest of your question.